# Verify set up of an iterated integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

> Let $$E= \int\int\int_W \frac{e^{-x}}{x} dv$$ where $W$ is five sided figure bounded by the planes $x=1+2z, z=x-2, z=y, y=0, z=0$

I want to set up an iterated integral.[image]

This is my attempt, can anybody please verify this?

Thanks.